# Generating an iso from Kernel built with GRUB/NASM/C

Tags: operating-system, kernel, grub, iso-image

I was following along with this [series of articles](http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/whatsleft.htm), and on the last page, he linked an iso image of the kernel that he produced. He doesn't mention this in the series, so that's my question... how do I generate an iso image from my kernel executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches I generally use.  The first is `mkisofs`, below is what I ripped out from a Makefile I use:

```
 mkisofs -quiet -R -b boot/grub/eltorito.img       \
         -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4           \
         -boot-info-table -o my_iso.iso iso_folder
```

You will need the El Torito image.  You can find more information on this approach [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Mkisofs).

The second approach (and the one I prefer) is to use `grub-mkrescue`:

```
grub-mkrescue -o bootable.iso iso
```

For this to work `iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg` will need to be a valid grub configuration file.  I prefer this approach because you can `dd` the result to a USB and boot.  The first approach is using the El Torito which is only for bootable optical media (e.g. CDs, DVDs) so you can's easily create a bootable USB with the first iso.

Comment: Minimal detailed working example with GAS + grub-mkrescue: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/tree/d217b180be4220a0b4a453f31275d38e697a99e0/multiboot/hello-world